# Python for .NET fails silently when calling System.Windows.Forms.Form constructor

Tags: c#, python, .net, python.net

### C# Code

I have the following **C#** code compiled into a library called "**MinimalFormsApp.dll**"

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsTest
{
    public static class CreateACoolWindow
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateWindow();
        }

        public static void CreateWindow()
        {
            Thread winFormsThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(StartFormApplication));
            winFormsThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            winFormsThread.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Started thread");
        }

        private static void StartFormApplication()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Console.WriteLine("EnableVisualStyles");
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Console.WriteLine("SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault");
            FormSubClass dmw = new FormSubClass();
            Console.WriteLine("Created window object");
            Application.Run(dmw);
        }
    }

    public class FormSubClass : Form
    {
        public FormSubClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FormSubClass Constructor called");
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting component init......");
            this.SuspendLayout();
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new Size(300, 500);
            this.Name = "FormSubClass";
            this.Text = "FormSubClass";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }
    }
}
```

### Python Code

Using **Python for .NET** with Python 2.7 for x86 I try to call the CreateWindow() method from this C# library.

My python code is as follows:

```
import clr
clr.AddReference("MinimalFormsApp")

from WindowsFormsTest import CreateACoolWindow
CreateACoolWindow.CreateWindow()

#Print some output
print "Mary had a little lamb,"
print "it's fleece was white as snow;"
print "and everywhere that Mary went",
print "her lamb was sure to go."
```

### Console Output

This is what Python prints out at the console

> Started thread
>      Mary had a little lamb,EnableVisualStyles
>      SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault
>
> it's fleece was white as snow;
>      and everywhere that Mary went her lamb was sure to go.
>      FormSubClass Constructor called

As can be seen, it does not print "Starting component init......" and it does not print "Created window object" and no Window is actually created. The Python program ends and produces no error messages saying why the window was not created.

If I call the same C# library from another C# program everything prints as would be expected and the window is created.

***Does anybody know why Python for .NET fails silently on the Forms constuctor?***

Comment: Did you tried with without using thread, just remove thread part and try to load it

Comment: Wow! Great suggestion. Commenting out the threading stuff and calling StartFormApplication() from within CreateWindow() causes it to succeed! You'll be my hero if you can tell me why!

Comment: That was a great tip! I now know why this is happening. When the Python program terminates, it kills everything running in .NET. If I give the python program something to do it does eventually load the window!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the main thread in Python terminates, it terminates everything running in .NET too.

In the example given above, the window does not have time to draw yet before the main Python thread terminates after printing the text to terminal.

Starting the .NET call inside a new python thread would prevent this action.

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled on this question while looking for another question.
I am a little late but I think I can provide insight into why this happens for anyone who has a similar problem.

When the CPython interpreter keeps track of threads, it places them in
three categories.

- Normal
- Daemon
- Alien

Normal is for regular python threads started through the threading module. The interpreter will not exit while any of these or the main thread are running.

Similarly, daemon threads are threads started though the threading module; however, they have been marked as daemons. In their case, the interpreter does NOT wait for them to terminate before exiting.

Finally, alien threads are threads started in the same process as CPython but were not started by any python code. The interpreter knows about these but does not know how to wait for them so treats them like daemon threads and does not wait for them to terminate before exiting.

For better handling of threading on windows (plus no GIL), check out IronPython. It may be slower but it just deals with .NET interactions like this better since it runs as native .NET.